# HTTP ERROR 431 только в Chrome при старте проекта в localhost на Angular 4

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, angular

Запускаю простой проект на Angular 4, но в Chrome всегда 431 ошибка, в других браузерах все хорошо работает.

Пробовал npm install, npm build, откат к старым версиям, не помогает.

Похоже что ошибка у меня локально, но не могу понять где.

Попробовать на другой машине нет возможности.

Comment: в режиме инкогнито тоже ошибка?

Comment: Нет, оказалось что в инкогнито все работает. 
А в чем причина такого поведения?

Comment: наверно расширения какие-нибудь, мжб впн или прокси